# Problema con varias etiquetas <a> y una única función js

Tags: javascript

Dentro de un "div" tengo varias etiquetas  cada una con un "id" diferente, que llaman a una misma función de `javascript`, con el evento `onclick`.

> ¿Como se en la función, cual etiqueta esta llamando la funcion?

Comment: puedes mostrar lo que has intentado?, parte del codigo para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Entenderemos mejor si en lugar de explicar el código que tienes, lo muestras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los llamas de esta manera:

```
    <a onClick="javascript: myFunc(this);">
```

... puedes en la funcion hacer lo siguiente:

```
function myFunc(element){
    var id = element.getAttribute("id");
}
```

... el parametro element es la etiqueta en si, accedes a ella sin la necesidad de hacerle un getElementById

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Ya implemente la solución que me diste, y obtuve lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Filino si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Comment: Gracias Mariano. Soy nuevo en este foro. Ahí voy aprendiendo a manejar las diferentes opciones del foro. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para eso debes mandar manualmente el ID como parámetro en tu función

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function my_onclick(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
</script>

<div>
<a href="#" id="l1" onClick="my_onclick(this.id)">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="l2" onClick="my_onclick(this.id)">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="l3" onClick="my_onclick(this.id)">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ya pude solucionar mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

**EN CASO DE OCUPAR JQUERY**

Prueba con esto, espero que sea de ayuda.

Cualquier cosa preguntas

```js
function saberLink(id){
  var texto = $("#link"+id).html();
  alert("Has hecho click en el link " +id+ ", y su valor es: "+ texto);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a id="link1" href="#" onclick="saberLink(1)">Link 1</a>
  <a id="link2" href="#" onclick="saberLink(2)">Link 2</a>
  <a id="link3" href="#" onclick="saberLink(3)">Link 3</a>
  <a id="link4" href="#" onclick="saberLink(4)">Link 4</a>
  <a id="link5" href="#" onclick="saberLink(5)">Link 5</a>
  <a id="link6" href="#" onclick="saberLink(6)">Link 6</a>
  <a id="link7" href="#" onclick="saberLink(7)">Link 7</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuestas. Me fue de mucha ayuda.

Comment: @Mariano Especificare la respuesta, para caso de personas que ocupen JQuery, así se entenderá para futuros usuarios. Gracias por la acotación.

Comment: @Filino que bueno poder haber sido de utilidad :)

Answer (score 1):

Sería mejor si a las mismas etiquetas les pones la misma clase no es necesario estan pensando en ID´s si la función de todos esos elementos será la misma.

```
<div>
  <a class="getLink" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a class="getLink" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a class="getLink" href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a class="getLink" href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a class="getLink" href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a class="getLink" href="#">Link 6</a>
  <a class="getLink" href="#">Link 7</a>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).on('click','.getLink',function(){
    var texto = $(this).text();
    console.log("La liga es: "+texto);
  });
</script>
```